# How to detect when a tableView display or update is complete (iOS)

Tags: xcode, events, ios, tableview

I would like to display the range (from x to y) of rows of data that are diaplayed in a tableView.  The problem is that when I update the data using [self.tableView reloadData], I cannot query the currently displayed data immediately (it will not yet be set).

So I need to have an event when the tableView display is completed any time it changes.  But I have not found this (yet).

Thanks for anyone who can point me to the way to meet this need.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. Please Please Please don't use a tableView as a data source. Your data should be kept in its own data model or at least separate from the view object. You should not be asking the tableView for data, a tableView is just a representation of data stored elsewhere. Update the data model, show that change in the tableView.

If you follow the proper model-view-controller (MVC) paradigm, there should be no reason for a callback like you're asking for to exist. That's why it doesn't.

Don't try to reinvent the wheel, just use MVC.

If you want to be alerted when something in your model changes, try using Key-Value Observing (KVO). Documentation for KVO and MVC can be found at developer.apple.com.

Good Luck!